# accessing the list declared in a class from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've declared a list in a class. I want to access the list from another class. How can I access the list from a module of another class?

```
// ClsUser.cs
namespace WebLll.ApiPayment.BusinessObject
{
    public class ClsUser
    {
        Data.MyEntity db = new Data.MyEntity("MyEntity1");

        public List<Data.GetPaymentRslt> BRIlstTxn = db.GetPayment(obj.PaymentCode, dtFrom, dtTo, obj.PaymentMode).ToList(); 

        //... remaining code
    }
}
// clsWebLllAPI.cs
namespace WebLll.ApiPayment.BusinessObject
{
    public class clsWebLllAPI : clsBaseApi
    {
        public void Initialize(api_rule_setup obj)
        {
            // access the BRIlstTxn here
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the list is `public` you can simply create an instance of the class and access it like follow,

```
ClsUser clsuser=new ClsUser();
List<Data.GetPaymentRslt> mylist=clsuser.BRIlstTxn; // Simply access PUBLIC field
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Accessing a field in an object is done by adding a period after the object name

But as good programming practice,I suggest you to use [Accessors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) over making a field `public` (need to know why, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c))

Suggestion code :

```
// ClsUser.cs
namespace WebLll.ApiPayment.BusinessObject
{
    public class ClsUser
    {
        Data.MyEntity db = new Data.MyEntity("MyEntity1");

        private List<Data.GetPaymentRslt> BRIlstTxn = db.GetPayment(obj.PaymentCode, dtFrom, dtTo, obj.PaymentMode).ToList(); 

        // Only GET . Provide protection over setting it
        public  List<Data.GetPaymentRslt> brIlstTxn{
           get
           {
               return BRIlstTxn;
           }
        }

        //... remaining code
    }
}
// clsWebLllAPI.cs
namespace WebLll.ApiPayment.BusinessObject
{
    public class clsWebLllAPI : clsBaseApi
    {
        public void Initialize(api_rule_setup obj)
        {
             ClsUser clsuser=new ClsUser();
             List<Data.GetPaymentRslt> mylist=clsuser.brIlstTxn; // Now you are accessing GET accesor rather than field directly
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have forgotten to create an instance of ClsUser in your second code block. You have it in the first block

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dot, member access operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zhxzbds.aspx) to access public/internal/protected data member (list) of other class.

```
namespace WebLll.ApiPayment.BusinessObject
{
    public class clsWebLllAPI : clsBaseApi
    {
        public void Initialize(api_rule_setup obj)
        {
            ClsUser clsUser = new ClsUser ();
            var lst = clsUser.BRIlstTxn;
        }

    }
}
```